# How to execute an SQL statement in VBA using " sign to Get the ID with RecordSet Access 2013

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am looking to execute the following code, the problem is, I need to put a String variable in the SQL which should use the "" sign inside the SQL statement.

The problem is, I cannot use multiple "". I tried using Char to use the sign " and convert it to a String, and that's when I got lost.

The code below shows 2 Functions. 1 To see if I get it right to print the correct SQL statement, the other is a Function to return the actual record ID which I will then use to add a new record.

What I mainly looking to do, is use the RecordSet to get a record ID of one of the records.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
Private Sub PrintSQLStatement_Click()

Dim strSQL As String
Dim strTmp As String
Dim i As Integer

strTmp = "UE243"

strSQL = "SELECT tbl_Sales.[ID], tbl_Sales.[SaleReference] FROM tbl_Sales WHERE (((tbl_Sales.[SaleReference])= "" + strTmp + ""));"

i = MsgBox(strSQL, vbOKOnly)

End Sub





Private Function GetSaleID(ByVal strSaleRef As String) As Integer

Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim strSQL As String
Dim ID As Integer

strSQL = "SELECT tbl_Sales.[ID], tbl_Sales.[SaleReference] FROM tbl_Sales WHERE    (((tbl_Sales.[SaleReference])= "" + strSaleRef + ""));"

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

ID = rs.GetID

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
db.Close

GetSaleID = ID

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid character escaping issues by using a QueryDef object to run a parameterized query like so:

```vbs
Private Function GetSaleID(ByVal strSaleRef As String) As Long
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim qd As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim ID As Long

    strSQL = _
            "PARAMETERS prmSaleRef TEXT(255);" & _
            "SELECT tbl_Sales.[ID] FROM tbl_Sales " & _
            "WHERE tbl_Sales.[SaleReference]=[prmSaleRef]"

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set qd = db.CreateQueryDef("", strSQL)
    qd!prmSaleRef = strSaleRef
    Set rs = qd.OpenRecordset(dbOpenSnapshot)

    ID = rs!ID

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set qd = Nothing
    db.Close
    Set db = Nothing

    GetSaleID = ID
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you very much Gord. This is perfect.